# Measure element while drawing using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, frontend, openlayers

I am implementing draw/modify features using OpenLayer in ReactJS and came across a very interesting question.

How can I draw a line and at the same time see how long it is in the real world (considering zoom and scale of the map).

**So for instance when I draw a line I would like to have an info like "real world length: x meters" where x is dynamically changing while extending the line.**

Is it possible to achieve such a functionality using **OpenLayers** and **ReactJS** (or just pure JS)? Is there maybe a better solution? Maybe anyone saw something that works this way?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: As in this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html use the getLength and getArea methods of ol/sphere, do not use methods of the geometry which is in web mercator coordinates

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't seen this this in the examples of OL till now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ol-ext/Overlay/Tooltips` can do it for you.
See example online: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.tooltip.measure.html
[image: measure tooltip]